# Turn off trackpad haptic feedback in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, trackpad, haptic-feedback

I came back to working with Xcode recently and I noticed that Interface Builder "rattles" my 2020 (Intel) Air's trackpad a lot by giving haptic feedback when elements snap to layout lines.

Is there any way to turn this off in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting user "SvepJIM" [from the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/64316?answerId=727286022#727286022):

> In case anyone reads this in 2022... I almost threw my computer out the (still closed) window when trying to move a label. The brain immediately reacts to the haptics and releases the trackpad, making it virtually impossible to use.
>
> It can (sort of) be disabled in the Trackpad -> Point & Click tab of System Preferences by deselecting "Force Click and haptic feedback.